# JQuery function POST on the same page works only twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function below allows me to use an href link to POST request to the same page. It works for the first 2 times I click on the link, but this function doesn't seem to be recognized after a third POST request.

```
 $(function() {
      $('.sort-link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(this.href, function(data) {
          $('.container').html(data);
        });
      });
    });
```

I need to modify the function to have it work even after a POST request has been submitted.

Comment: You need to debug it in browser console. What does browser console says after third request? It should show some error messages in red color

Comment: There is no error. The link simply does its default action which is to send a GET request. I need to override that default action with a POST request. Hence, my jquery function.

Comment: It is DOM related issue. Instead of $('.sort-link').on('click') try using $(document).on("click", '.sort-link', function(event) { 
    alert("clicked...");
});

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks @Elvin85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Elvin85's advice, I revised my function as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", '.sort-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.href, function(data) {
      $('.container').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

It was a DOM-related issue.